# How to rename Pandas dataframe with unicode character

Tags: pandas

I have Pandas Dataframe that comes from Excel import:

```
Trade   Symbol  Type    Signal  Date    Price   Contracts   Profit (¤)  Run-up (¤)  Drawdown (¤)
0   1   FOXA    EntryLong   Buy 2000-10-18  34.69   200 0   0   0
1   NaN NaN ExitLong    Sell    2000-10-18  34.69   200 NaN NaN NaN
2   2   TXN EntryLong   Buy 2000-10-18  36.88   200 1774    1900    0
3   NaN NaN ExitLong    Sell    2000-10-19  45.75   200 NaN NaN NaN
```

I need to rename "Profit (¤)" to "Profit" but cannot get rid of the "¤" sign.

I am using:

```
trades.rename(columns={'Trade #':'Trade','Symbol Name':'Symbol','Profit (¤)':'Profit','Run-up (¤)':'Runup','Drawdown (¤)':'Drawdown'}, inplace=True)
```

which does not work.

```
list(trades)
```

gets:

```
['Trade',
 'Symbol',
 u'Type',
 u'Signal',
 u'Date',
 u'Price',
 u'Contracts',
 u'Profit (\xa4)',
 u'Run-up (\xa4)',
 u'Drawdown (\xa4)']
```

Any tip how to rename the colums with the special character?
Thank you.

Comment: So does `trades.rename(columns={'Profit (\xa4)':'Profit'}, inplace=True)` work?

Comment: As an aside seeing as all you're doing is removing the additional weird character you could just do `trades.columns = trades.columns.str.split().str[0]`

Comment: trades.rename(columns={'Profit (\xa4)':'Profit'}, inplace=True) does not work. I get error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa4' in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: trades.columns = trades.columns.str.split().str[0] helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like all you're doing is just dropping the erroneous additional character, as it's delimited by a space you can just overwrite the column names by [splitting](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split) on the space:

```
In [104]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Trade',
 'Symbol',
 u'Type',
 u'Signal',
 u'Date',
 u'Price',
 u'Contracts',
 u'Profit (\xa4)',
 u'Run-up (\xa4)',
 u'Drawdown (\xa4)'])
df

Out[104]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Trade, Symbol, Type, Signal, Date, Price, Contracts, Profit (¤), Run-up (¤), Drawdown (¤)]
Index: []

In [105]:   
df.columns.str.split().str[0]

Out[105]:
Index(['Trade', 'Symbol', 'Type', 'Signal', 'Date', 'Price', 'Contracts',
       'Profit', 'Run-up', 'Drawdown'],
      dtype='object')
```

So the following should work for you:

```
trades.columns = trades.columns.str.split().str[0]
```